# Flutter GCP IoT Core

Tags: python, flutter, raspberry-pi

I tried to change the status of the device in GCP IoT Core using Python code (on Raspberry Pi). I want to bring the device status using the flutter app and send command to control it.

Is there any code with this example? Shall I use Firebase?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/cloudiot/v1.dart';

final _credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(r'''
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxxxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxx.............
\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
''');

const _scopes = [CloudiotApi.CloudiotScope];

Future<void> main() async {
  final httpClient = await clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials, _scopes);
  try {
    final cia = CloudiotApi(httpClient);
    var device1 = await cia.projects.locations.registries.devices.get(
        "projects/<project name>/locations/<location>/registries/<registery>/devices/<device name>");
    var stateTime = device1.lastStateTime;
    var dconfig = device1.config;
    var dState = device1.state.binaryData;
    var data= SendCommandToDeviceRequest();

    data.binaryData = 'qwerqwer';

    cia.projects.locations.registries.devices.sendCommandToDevice(data,
        "projects/xxxx/locations/xxxx-xxxx/registries/xxxxx/devices/xxxx");

    print(dState);

  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  } finally {
    httpClient.close();
  }
}
```